# Why User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always true even after logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on AspnetCore 2.1 MVC application , it has windows integrated authentication. I have implemented login, logout functionality using await HttpContext.SignInAsync(). it is cookie bases authentication, the cookie expires after specified time I provide.

My issue is I have to hide logout from nav bar after user logs out. but in _layout.cshtml , @User.Identity.Is authenticated always true even after user hits logout. Any help ? below is the code I am using

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="InitiatedCases" asp-action="Index">Initiated Cases</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="SubmittedCases" asp-action="Index">Submitted Cases</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="UserAccessLogs" asp-action="Index">User Access Log</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a></li>
                    <li><p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">@User.Identity.Name!</p></li>

                </ul>
            }
            else
            {
                <p></p>

            }

            </div>
```

below is login functionality

```
var usrRole = _dbContext.UserAccess.Where(r => r.UserId == loginUser.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginUser.UserId.ToString()));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("DisplayName", loginUser.UserId));

if (usrRole != null)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, usrRole.UserRole.ToString()));
}

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true,
        IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_iconfiguration.GetValue<double>("Session:TimeOutInMinutes")),
        AllowRefresh = false
    });
```

Comment: Show us how you are logging out the user.

Comment: How are you login out the user? Are you calling something like "await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(AuthenticationScheme)" when you log the user out?

Comment: @Manny , yes I am calling "await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)"

Comment: Then that should be in your question, since you are asking about it.

Comment: Also, did you ever solve this? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be using windows integrated authentication - although i am not sure.

The browser uses Windows Integrated Authentication - which means it automatically logs the user in using their windows credentials - without asking.

That's why IsAuthenticated is always true.

**Additional thoughts:**
I have not tried below code, but there is something called as IISServerOptions.
You can try them to check if that works for you.

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => 
{
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
});
```

Comment: I used IISOptions, as IISServerOptions not working. after using it. I was getting null value in   var user = _accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;, where _accessor is object of IHttpContextAccessor. so I am not getting logged in user name after that. I am collecting logged in user from this and in db checking role and this way my entire application is designed. Any Idea ? thanks in advance.

Comment: @LalitSingh Im strugglying with the same